# A failure occured while executing a PreparedStatement batch request

Tags: java, mongodb, jdbc

I'm trying to insert so many records from MongoDB to Teradata using JDBC's PreparedStatement(pstmt).

I'm trying to add a batch to the pstmt and finally trying to execute a batch using the below piece of code:

```
pstmt.setInt(1, 101);
pstmt.setString(2, "mkyong101");
pstmt.addBatch();
pstmt.executeBatch();
```

While trying to insert a lot of records into Teradata from MongoDB, I'm facing "**A failure occured while executing a PreparedStatement batch request. The Parameter set was not executed and should be resubmitted individually using pstmt executeUpdate method**" exception.

I'm totally stuck here with no clue.
Can anyone please help me out regarding the same...

Comment: Please post your code and the error stack trace for any of us to help you solve the problem!

Comment: Will this kind of error occurs due to space issue in teradata? Because, I'm able to load 10,000 records from Mongo to Teradata and later I'm facing the above mentioned exception.

Comment: I'm not very sure about space creating any such issues, but a possible solution for this is to reduce your batch size and execute!

Comment: I had reduced the batch size from 1000 to 100 and executed the program, but the number of insertion of the records has been increased to 10,100 and after that the application is failing with the same error. When I try to free up the space in teradata and had a run of the application then it is inserting 21000 records

Comment: Actually I have 2.5 lakh records in mongodb and after space freeup, I'm able to load 21000 records with batch size=1000 out of 2.5 lakhs and again facing the same exception.

Comment: Finally, able to resolve the issue. It's mainly due to space issue... Thanks  N00b Pr0grammer for ur help ...

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by allocating more space to the database where I was inserting records.

1. In Teradata administrator, go to 'Tools' > 'Move Space...'
2. In the Move Space dialog, in the 'From Database' field, enter your default database.
3. In the 'To Database' field, enter your database you are inserting rows.
4. In 'Number of Bytes' field, enter appropriate amount.
5. Click 'Move'.